# Attempting to install Portia on OSX or Ubuntu

Tags: macos, python-2.7, ubuntu, portia

Could someone help me? I have been over and over installing Portia. All goes well until I get to the point where I am using the twistd command and I get this:

(portia)Matts-Mac-mini:slyd matt$ twistd -n slyd 
Traceback (most> recent call last): File "/Users/matt/portia/bin/twistd", line 14, in run() File "/Users/matt/portia/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 27, in run app.run(runApp, ServerOptions) File "/Users/matt/portia/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 642, in run runApp(config) File "/Users/matt/portia/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run() File "/Users/matt/portia/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 376, in run self.application = self.createOrGetApplication() File "/Users/matt/portia/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 436, in createOrGetApplication ser = plg.makeService(self.config.subOptions) File "/Users/matt/portia/portia/slyd/slyd/tap.py", line 74, in makeService root = create_root(config) File "/Users/matt/portia/portia/slyd/slyd/tap.py", line 41, in create_root from .projectspec import create_project_resource File "/Users/matt/portia/portia/slyd/slyd/projectspec.py", line 5, in from slybot.validation.schema import get_schema_validator

**ImportError: No module named slybot.validation.schema.**

I also noted that when trying to do the 'pip install -r requirements.txt' even though I am in the correct directory( [virtualenv-name]/portia/slyd), the requirements.txt file is not in the slyd directory but in the portia directory.

I am going crazy here and any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like There is a mistake in the installation guide.

The guide should be:

```
virtualenv ENV_NAME --no-site-packages
source ENV_NAME/bin/activate
cd ENV_NAME
git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia.git
cd portia
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e ./slybot
cd slyd
twistd -n slyd
```

This worked for me. Hopefully it will work for you too.

Comment: Probably you will also need to do first: easy_install -U pip